# Kubernetes : refering to containerPorts from services with their name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

Hi the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#containerport-v1-core)  says about the name field in containers.ports :

> name  If specified, this must be an IANA_SVC_NAME and unique within the pod. Each named port in a pod must have a unique name. Name for the port that can be referred to by services.

I tried to use it in my service as follows but I have an error from the parser :

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: banana-app
  labels:
    app: banana
spec:
  containers:
    - name: banana-app
      image: hashicorp/http-echo
      args:
        - "-text=banana"
      ports:
      - containerPort: 5678
        name: bananaport
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: banana-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: banana
  ports:
    - port: bananaport
```

The parser error is :

> error: error validating "temp.yml": error validating data: ValidationError(Service.spec.ports[0].port): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServicePort.port: got "string", expected "integer"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

So I guess I am not using the port name correctly. What is the correct way to use the port name in my service?

Thanks in advance,
Abdelghani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `port` field represents the port at which the `Service` object listens to and the `targetPort` represents the port at which the container is listening.

Try this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: banana-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: banana
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: bananaport
```